# Is there a desktop (Windows) application I can run SOQL queries with?

Tags: soql, developer-productivity

I am new to Salesforce and so far I have found three ways to run queries:

- Developer Console
- Workbench
- Force.com IDE (Eclipse)

These work for quick ad-hoc queries but for writing more complex queries e.g. to assess data quality the functionality is lacking. I'd like to have syntax highlighting, line numbering, auto-completion, auto-formatting, etc. I've used Oracle SQL Developer extensively and it would be perfect, but as far as I can tell it can't connect to SFDC without ODBC drivers which are very expensive.

The official Force.com Explorer appears to have been abandoned ([Has Force.com Explorer been abandoned?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10008/has-force-com-explorer-been-abandoned)) so that isn't an option. What about the FuseIT SFDC Explorer (http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer.aspx)? Any other suggestions?

Comment: If your linked post weren't 3 years old this might almost be a duplicate. My how time flies! How about [this one](http://cloudingo.com/cloudingo-studio/)? Does it have to be a free option?

Comment: @AdrianLarson If it is not free, I would need a convincing argument for my company to pay for it...

Comment: It seems that Cloudingo Studio is still using TLS 1.0, which SFDC recently removed support for (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221207). I contacted Cloudingo support about this issue; currently it will not connect to Salesforce.

Comment: Wow that's crazy they didn't see that coming and update their product. I bet they have a lot of angry customers...

Comment: It is a free product so it is not their highest priority...still I have to imagine this  was announced a lot time ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is also a new IDE [The Welkin Suite](https://welkinsuite.com/) where you can run queries. Not sure about all what you've asked but there is line numbering :) They also have a forum where you can request a new feature [here](https://forum.welkinsuite.com/forum/7-feature-requests/) there is chance they implement it in future releases as they release pretty often with new features.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good as well. I will have to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Other available options:

## 1 <s>[Real Force Explorer](https://bitbucket.org/realforceexplorer/real-force-explorer/wiki/Home)</s>.

Real Force Explorer is now branded as [Datasert Realforce](https://www.datasert.com/products/realfire)

Pros:

- DML operations available within context menu
- syntax highlighting
- data export

Cons:

- lack of auto-completion
- annoying limits, even for paid versions ([pricing page](https://www.datasert.com/products/realfire/pricing))

## 2 [Illuminated Cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/home/apexsoql)

Pros:

- auto-completion
- line numbering
- very useful [shortcuts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7T4y3_VJbA&t=6m45s)
- syntax highlighting

Cons:

- No DML operations within context menu
- no data export

## 3 [JetForcer](https://jetforcer.com/pages/features/soql-query-editor)

Pros and Cons are pretty similar to the Illuminated Cloud (this is also a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA)

Comment: Looks pretty nice!

Comment: Do you have any affiliation to this product? I believe there is a forum policy about disclosure of such affiliations, though I'm not sure.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, not really. I've just pasted some of the information from their wiki. I am using this tool instead of force.com explorer.

Comment: Gotcha. Even if it's disclosing you don't have such affiliation it's probably a good idea when recommending tools/products.

Answer (score 1):

There is lightweight application Force.com Explorer, built with Adobe Air, so it is cross-platform. It's main purpose is running queries. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/ForceExplorer

Comment: Huh, looks like Force.com Explorer wasn't abandoned after all...

Comment: @Math1000 The linked product page says it was last updated to 0.58A in October 2011. I'd say the Adobe Air version has also been abandoned.

Comment: @DanielBallinger it still works and I am still using it

Comment: @VladyslavKushney Great. Has it been updated recently? Newer API versions give you access to more functionality.

Comment: @DanielBallinger it has not been updated, but I am satisfied with current version. I agree that it is more easy to execute queries from IDE, but Force.com explorer has advantage when you want to access your org's data quickly. You login and it retrieves metadata dynamically.